# mod_perl odd behaviour with system() or exec() call or backticks

Tags: perl, exec, system, mod-perl

I developped a simple script in Perl that let's me verify if USB key is mounted or not and eventually unmount it.

I am not sure if problem is related to programming or configuration, if I was wrong let me know and I will repost my question on server configuration related stack.

Basic issue is:
When I execute those scripts in terminal using `Perl` it works perfectly fine, althou when I do it in the browser using `mod_perl` it shows some pretty odd behaviour.

## Sources

### panelmin.pl

This program simply outputs a message that indicates if the system device `/dev/sda1` is mounted in the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>USB test</title>";
print "</head><body>";

my $mounted = `df -h | grep /dev/sda1`;

if ($mounted eq '') {
        print '<h1>USB device not connected</h1>';
        print $mounted;
}
else {
        print '<h1>Device is connected</h1>';
}
print '</body></html>';
```

### umount.pl

This program umounts the `/dev/sda1` device from the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>Umount</title></head><body>";
system("sudo", "umount", "/dev/sda1");
print "</body></html>";
```

## Test scenario

1. Manually mounting the device `/dev/sda1`, (it is declared in `fstab`):

   ```
   $ mount -a
   ```

   Making sure the device is mounted in the system:

   ```
   $ mount
   /dev/sda1 on /mnt/usbstick type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0137,dmask=0027,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
   ```
2. Executing `panelmin.pl` in the web browser (I will use curl for the purpose of clean output):

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/admin/Q/panel/panelmin.pl
   <html><head><title>USB test</title></head><body><h1>Device is connected</h1></body></html>
   ```

   As we can see, the output is correct. It detected the through linux command `df -h` that the device `/dev/sda1` is mounted in the system.
3. Executing `umount.pl` in the web browser in order to umount the device:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/admin/Q/panel/umount.pl
   <html><head><title>Umount</title></head><body></body></html>
   ```
4. Verifying if the device is umounted using both `panelmin.pl` script in the web browser and linux command line.

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/admin/Q/panel/panelmin.pl
   <html><head><title>USB test</title></head><body><h1>USB device not connected</h1></body></html>
   ```

   Seems to be correct, but let's verify it manually with `df -h` command:

   ```
   $ df -h | grep /dev/sda1
   /dev/sda1        15G  366M   15G   3% /mnt/usbstick
   ```

   As we can see the device is still mounted in the system.
5. Let's retry the whole process but this time instead of executing scripts in the browser we will launch them manually with `Perl` in the terminal. First lets umount the device. This will also show that the user is in sudoers and script can umount it.

   ```
   $ sudo umount /dev/sda1
   $ df -h | grep /dev/sda1
   ```

   Let's repeat the process.

   ```
   $ mount -a (as superuser)
   $ df -h | grep /dev/sda1
   /dev/sda1        15G  366M   15G   3% /mnt/usbstick
   ```

   And finally the test:

   ```
   $ perl panelmin.pl 
   Content-type:text/html
   <html><head><title>USB test</title></head><body><h1>Device is connected</h1></body>

   $ perl umount.pl 
   Content-type:text/html
   <html><head><title>Umount</title></head><body></body></html>

   $ perl panelmin.pl 
   Content-type:text/html
   <html><head><title>USB test</title></head><body><h1>USB device not connected</h1></body></html>

   $ df -h | grep /dev/sda1
   ```

   Now `df -h | grep /dev/sda1` returned empty string, it has proven that `umount.pl` managed to umount the device from the system, but only if executed in the shell with `Perl`.

## Attempts to solve the issue

1. Making sure the user who executes `sudo umount /dev/sda1` in `umount.pl` has right to do so, I verified it by executing `whoami` inside the script and printing it in the output.
2. Trying different syntax of `system()`, for example separating the arguments or executing it all as one command.
3. I verified if my mod_perl executes scripts in `taint mode`, because I heard it may influence executing external processes. As a matter of fact in my `httpd.conf` there is no `PerlTaintCheck On` and if I understand it correctly, it would influence the execution with dynamic arguments (for security reasons), in case of my script it is same command each time.
4. I tryed to use different functions, replace `System` by `Exec` or by backticks etc.
5. I tryed to use `Apache2::SubProcess`, just like they do it [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/mod_perl/docs/api/Apache2/SubProcess.pod) , but I must admit I'm not sure if I did it correctly, I'm new to Perl and this (and all other available on net) example is just horrible, for example `$r` variable is never initiated in their code, I just declarated it as `Apache2::RequestRec object`, it didn't work.
6. I tryed to change env variables like they explained [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/modperl/ch10_02.htm) in subsection `10.2.6. Starting a Long-Running External Program`
7. I verified the logs in Apache directory, have found errors but not related to those scripts, I didn't post them here because I didn't wanted it to bee too messy.

## Interpretation

The fact it works with `Perl` and not with `mod_perl` is not that surprising, what I find the most strange is with `mod_perl` the script `panelmin.pl` seems to works fine with it's `system()` launch and suddenly after executing `umount.pl` it does not work correctly anymore. For now I am out of ideas, I find this behaviour odd and I count on you guys. I hope someone knows what should I do. Thanks.

## Requested results

1. Capturing the output of System in `umount.pl`.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
   print "<html><head><title>Umount</title></head><body>";
   my $res = `sudo umount /dev/sda1`;
   print "$res</body></html>";
   ```

   And the result is void:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/admin/Q/panel/umount.pl
   <html><head><title>Umount</title></head><body></body></html>
   ```

Comment: Can I suggest capturing the output of that 'umount' command. My guess would be that the call via mod_perl is running with different permissions, and may not be able to sudo.

Comment: Check return value of `system()` or use `use autodie qw(:all);`

Comment: It took some time to compile autodie with all dependencies (I work on Raspberry Pi) so I left it for the night and now I just verified what you suggested, unfortunately it still won't unmount the device..

Comment: Capture the output to stderr as well from your shelled out commands.  `sudo umount /dev/sda1 2>1`

Comment: Thanks Miller. I added `2>1` at the end of the command, captured output with backticks, output was void just like in other cases, and I also executed the script from shell using Perl and also executed the command itself, there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was not programming related, it was server configuration related.

It was Apache's fault. It worked in multithread / multiprocess environment. I'm not sure why, but it made him be unable to process `system()` functions. When I limited it to work in single process mode the issue was solved.

Even knowing the problem is not programming related, I think it should stay here, since when this issue occur, it may be difficult to identify the source of the problem and I suppose StackOverflow would be the first place to look for for most beginners.